# Woocommerce display category title and image for the product

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

In Wordpress Woocommerce how to properly display category title and image for the product in Storefront theme?

Comment: You can override the template or you can use hooks , but first you should mention in which page you want to display and second thing if you have gone through codex( in both wordpress and woocommerce ) you can get how to do this easily .

Comment: I have the result page where I have all my products displayed, so I need a function? Can you help me how to write this function to do this and where to paste, sorry new to this)

Comment: Is it the shop page ?

Comment: No I have a page called Result where I have all my products displayed as a  result: here it is http://carparts.x10.bz/results/?make=2&model=1&syear=1&cfm=Audi&cfmo=A4&cfy=2003. Instead of showing just the product I need to show its Category above too. Thank you for your help

Comment: can you post the template page code you are using for this page ?

Comment: It using the default template, not sure where to find it

Comment: Do you know how to edit a page ? if yes then go there and in the right side of the page you can see the template name .

Comment: I added the code see at the end of the page thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get category ID at first :

```
global $post;    
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
        break;
    }
```

Next when you have it - try to get thumbnail ID for current category:

```
// get the thumbnail id user the term_id
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $product_cat_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
```

And at last - getting image:

```
// get the image URL
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Can you help me where to put this code, is it in function.php of the theme? thanks

Comment: In functions.php you need to create hook (maybe hook_init or hook_post_save). In this hook ypu need to add this code and the next:
$product_cat_img = get_post_meta($post_id, 'category_img', true);
if(!$product_cat_img){
    set_post_meta($post_id, 'category_img');
}

So in template you just getting this meta and print if in image as i shows in above

Comment: @DrHolera He need to create hook or function , I think he need to create function and use available hook.

Comment: I have the result page where I have all my products displayed, so I need a function? Can you help me how to write this function to do this and where to paste, sorry new to this)

Comment: Please learn this http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks documentation for solve your problev

Comment: Thank you guys and DrHolera its starts to get to work a bit I think I figured out: and thanks for help this works: global $post;    
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
        break;
    } 
// get the thumbnail id user the term_id
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $product_cat_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
// get the image URL
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';

Answer (score 0):

That's the template code:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
            do_action( 'storefront_page_before' );
            ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

            <?php
            /**
             * @hooked storefront_display_comments - 10
             */
            do_action( 'storefront_page_after' );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: [mmy_filter_result] thats in my result page editor too

Comment: if it is  using a shortcode you should go for the code of shortcode and for this template , It is using another template `content-page.php` , you should post that codes too .there should be something like `do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );` and the template part it should use is `content-product.php` so the code should be `get_template_part('content', 'product')` . another thing you can use is `pre_get_posts` hook you can also use this to get your job done.

Comment: The bigger problem is you are having no good idea of wordpress or woocommerce .Neither you can do anything as your own nor you are able to understand it clearly.

Comment: Yes Im new to woocomerce and wordpress and I appreciate your help

Comment: You should spend some days in wordpress codex than in woocommerce codex, I have spend nearly 4 months there.

Comment: use `content-product.php` in place of `content-page.php` and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, here is content-page.php of the theme:

```
<?php
    /**
     * The template used for displaying page content in page.php
     *
     * @package storefront
     */
?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php
        /**
         * @hooked storefront_page_header - 10
         * @hooked storefront_page_content - 20
         */
        do_action( 'storefront_page' );
    ?>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

And this is content-product.php of woocommerece plugin

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

// Store loop count we're currently on
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] ) ) {
    $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = 0;
}

// Store column count for displaying the grid
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) ) {
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 );
}

// Ensure visibility
if ( ! $product || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    return;
}

// Increase loop count
$woocommerce_loop['loop']++;

// Extra post classes
$classes = array();
if ( 0 == ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] || 1 == $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) {
    $classes[] = 'first';
}

if ( 0 == $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) {
    $classes[] = 'last';
}
?>
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

        /**
         * woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>
   </a>
   <?php
       /**
        * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook
        *
        * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
        */
       do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
   ?>
</li>
```